# What is this leaking pipe and how can I fix it?

Tags: plumbing, leak, pipe

A pipe below my sink started leaking. I was able to find the pipe that leaks, but couldn’t determine it’s function and/or a potential fix.

It is a gray color pipe with metal stripes. It folds near the bottom and has a somewhat biggish black attachment near the bottom. The pipe goes back up and has a smallish white attachment up there. Above the white attachment, pipe’s shape is solid and right there I think it says “MEOPERL RPE DM6”.

Bottom part image: https://ibb.co/GsMdJsC

Top part image: https://ibb.co/ZSdhXQK

The leak is happening where it curves near the bottom. Curved part is wet and dripping. When I work my way up in either direction, the pipe is dry. Hence, I am not sure what’s causing the leak.

Any clues what’s causing the leak and how I can fix it and also should I attempt fixing it myself?

Comment: it's the hand sprayer. the black thing is a weight to retract the sprayer via gravity. Its wet at the bottom because water flows downward. It could be leaking at either end. If it's always wet, the line side is leaking. If it's only wet after you spray things, the handle side is leaking. you can get a replacement and it's not that hard of job, one of the easier plumbing DIYs.

Comment: If it's actually only wet near the bottom then the hose itself has cracked. Often times, these hoses come with quick connect fittings and must be replaced with OEM parts - you can't just buy any old replacement part off the shelf.

Comment: @dandavis that looks a _lot_ like an answer...

Comment: as @FreeMan states, these hoses are usually specific by manufacturer and model so you will likely need that info to procure a replacement hose. In my experience it is more likely that your problem lies at a connection point so check carefully with a flashlight under normal operating conditions (note- even if at one of the hose connectors, it still means you need a new hose...) Another possibility is water leaking from the faucet/sink splash zone above, and just dripping down.

Comment: Thanks folks! I was able to confirm that this was the hand sprayer. It is always wet and that is the bottom section where it curves. Now I think that the hose is cracked. I am now trying to figure out the brand and model to get a replacement hose. Otherwise, I might need to get a new faucet with all parts.